# Robotframework : How to retrieve the answer of a request

Tags: selenium, http-post, robotframework

I would like to test the activation of a user. To validate the creation of a user, I click on a "Valid" button and the front-end requests the back-end to send a POST request.
My goal is to retrieve the answer to this query.

I have tried these keywords:

```
*** Setting ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    HttpLibrary.HTTP    

*** Keyword ***
!Confirm entry
    [Arguments]    ${id_button}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${id_button}
    Click Element    ${id_button}
    Response Status Code Should Equal    200
```

Or

```
*** Setting ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Keyword ***
!Confirm entry
    [Arguments]    ${id_button}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${id_button}
    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return    Click Element    ${id_button}
```

These two solutions don't give me satisfaction.
Would you, please, have an idea of the keywords to use in Robotframework to solve my problem?

Comment: please add the settings section? which library your using? selenium or http ?

Comment: I added the requested information.@navarasu

Comment: What does "don't give me satisfaction" mean? Do they throw errors, and if so, what errors? If they don't throw errors, what do they do that is different from what you expect?

Comment: The first solution returns the error "No request available, use e.g. GET to create one.". The second returns the error "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <button id="validUser" class="btn-smt-Important" name="validBtn"> could not be scrolled into view". @BryanOakley

Comment: please [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 3):

`Click Element`  will not return status code as you expected. You can't get the status code using selenium.

`Response Status Code Should Equal`  is HTTP library and it will work for only when it is followed HTTP Request like `GET`,`POST` keywords in HTTP library.

```
Example      
    HTTP Context    httpstat.us
    GET  /302
    Response Status Code Should Equal   302
```

It will not work with selenium keywords.

Comment: I take note of your remark. Do you know an alternative to my problem? @Navarasu

Comment: What you are trying to do? Test http request or selenium? If you want to verify http api, purely use HTTP library and do post request and you can verify response as in the answer. If you want to verify UI , to confirm a post request check with UI directly for success message or check the db whether it is added something which to confirm post action is successful

Comment: I thought we could juggle both libraries. I would like to retrieve the answer of the POST command sent. So if I understand correctly, I have to connect to the reception and listen to the port in order to receive the message?The receiver of the message is http://127.0.0.1:1234. Could you, please, help me write the correct syntax? @Navarasu

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by the already given answers mixing HttpLibrary and SeleniumLibrary will not give you access to the status code of the http exchanges between the UI and the webserver.

If you want to ensure that all calls from the browser are given a http 200, then you have to route the traffic through a proxy. In this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619646/6152737) working example for the use of BrowserMob proxy is given.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat what the others have already said, the browser's requests cannot be intercepted by selenium.
For the purpose of different alternatives, another option to do that is to use Service Workers - that'll get the network traffic and call js in your control that can store (or even modify) the transferred data.

The setup for that can be quite complicated (injecting the worker and the js, then communicating with it from robotframework), here's a [very through SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815800/3446126) to get started on it.